# Monitoring tool splitting gui and backend code in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have an application which monitors some devices. I can send a string to the device, and receive text back from the device.

What I need is to make a log file (just .txt) which logs all data sent / received by the device. This should be displayed live in a the application.

Currently what I do is write the logs to a rich textbox and from there to a file. But I want to split the backend code (interfacing with the device and creating the log file) from the gui. This to make the communication interface with the device more portable.

As I am thinking through this process I face one issue: How to update the logs live in my application? I can think of this option: Make a timer and make the gui update on a time interval. but this does not feels terrible. It would be nice to have a buffer in between, and update the gui if the buffer has changed.

Any tips on how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could make your log content [IObservable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx) and make your UI subscribe to its changes?

Another option would be to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and and use a PropertyChangedEventHandler to be notified of changes.

Here's a code snippet showing you how to do it with the NotifyPropertyChanged:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
public class YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    protected void AddLogLine(String log)
    {
        // do your process
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Log");
    }
}
```

To register to the changes you simply do something like (in your UI constructor):

```
YourClassInstance.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(MyFunctionToHandleLogChanges);
```

Note: make sure you properly remove and add again the handler if you change YourClassInstance

And then to update your UI, in your UI class again:

```
void MyFunctionToHandleLogChanges(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Log")
    {
        // Update UI
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at the IObservable as well. What I found is that this is more for broadcasting, where I just need a single connection. The alternative is as you posted, to use eventhandlers. So in my case I feel the best method is to use the events. Am I correct here?

Comment: I think so, if there's a better option, I'm not using it myself in my code :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I'll accept it after I tested and impemented it!

Comment: I've been experimenting with this. I ran into 2 problems, 1 i could solve myself: you need to add `using System.ComponentModel;` in the sender class. but in the listener class I found i need to add `using Microsoft.Build.Utilities` as reference. But than I can not figure how to add the `PropertyChangedEventHandler(MyFunction...)` to the `Logger.PorpertyChanged` PropertyChanged does not exist in `Microsoft.Build.Utilities`. Any tips?

Comment: Oh sorry, when I said logger I didn't mean Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Logger, I meant your logging class :) The PropertyChanged is something you add to your class (see my first code section)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19581/discussion-between-2pietjuh2-and-emartel)