# Catch button click event on different class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winforms applications which should be able to communicate with a custom device. I have a main window which has a button "Disconnect". I have a user control which handles the logging, and a class (SerialCom) which handles all communciation.

When I load the user control I also setup the com port in the SerialCom class. This class receives data, and sends it to the user control via INotifyPropertyChanged, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381160/monitoring-tool-splitting-gui-and-backend-code-in-c-sharp) for more detail here.

I want to acces the class SerialCom from the MainForm, without having to `new` the SerialCom class. but the SerialCom class is first created on the user control. (so, if I `new` the SerialCom class from the MainForm, the serial port will not be open, so I cannot close it.)

Any tips on how to acces class A from class B and C without having to new class A again? I was thinking about passing the event between the forms, is this the best option?

Comment: there are many options here: you could pass a reference to the object from A to B, you could have a "program" class which is accessible by any form in your application. You could have a delegate for an event. You could use an observer/observable construction. The world is at your feet. :)

Comment: question updated to make more clear

Comment: Would it help to make `SerialCom` a singleton?

Comment: just expose SerialCom instance from your UserControl using property and add the event handler in your form.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar thanks this did work, I tried this before but could not figure how to get it working, and now it does work perfectly fine :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your `SerialCom` class into a singleton. That way you have an instance that many classes can access. But please make sure to make this thread safe!

See [this for making thread safe singletons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I used the thread safe example from microsoft indeed. It works as expected :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for a singleton. Basically, a single is an object that only allows a single instance to be initialised, and provides a mechanism (through static methods/properties) to access this instance from anywhere.

Here is a simple implementation that i found at the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

```
using System;

public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Which it even says in the article. =D